# GZIP Up To Byte Limit Without Copy

Tags: python, gzip

I'd like to pack records into a list of io.ByteIO using gzip. I want to set a max_size for each pack that I don't want to exceed. The problem is I don't know if I'll exceed that size with a new record until I do. Once it's gone over size I don't have a good way of undoing that addition.

```
def pack_gz_records(records: List[any], max_size: int) -> List[io.BytesIO]:
    packets = []
    
    mem_file = io.BytesIO()
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mem_file, mode="w")

    for record in records:
        if gz.size >= max_size:
            # Size exceeded limit. Add this mem file to the package and cut a new mem file
            mem_file.seek(0)
            packets.append(mem_file)
            mem_file = io.BytesIO()
            gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mem_file, mode="w")
        
        gz.write(serialize(record))

    if gz.size:
        mem_file.seek(0)
        packets.append(mem_file)

    return packets
```

Is there a way to undo a write, or "peek" a write in an efficient way without making a copy of all of the bytes for each record before writing?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know how much will be written until you write it. I suggest you just set your limit a little lower than what you actually want, so that going over by a small amount is still acceptable.

Comment: What will you do if some single record is too large to compress to less than your maximum size?

Comment: @MarkAdler In my case that would be a bug and so i'm not worried about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the `zlib` library (instead of `gzip`). Create the compression object with `wbits=31` to select the gzip format. The `copy()` function can make a copy of the compression object before adding the next record. After making a copy, add the next record to the original object and flush with `Z_BLOCK`. If the result, plus some margin for the gzip trailer, doesn't go over your limit, then delete the copy. If it does go over, then delete the object that went over, and go back and finish (flush with `Z_FINISH`) the compression on the copied object.

This assumes that your records are at least several K in size, so that compression is not impacted significantly by the flushing. If your records are small, you should compress several records before flushing. (Experiment with the number of records per flush to measure the compression impact.) If you'd like to get fancy, when you go over your limit and back up, you could follow that with a binary search to determine the number of records to just fill it up.

Comment: I will look at this approach. The records themselves aren't large but there are billions of them being processed in a live stream. How would the bin search approach work? Don't the records needs to be added to the gzip before you can determine where the cut is?

Comment: Let's say you're adding 32 records at a time until you run into your limit. Now you have 32 that didn't fit. Use the same object-copy approach to try adding the first 16 of those. Also too many. Now try adding 8. That worked. Ok, how about 12. Yep. 14? No. Try 13. That fit! We're done.

Comment: I see what you mean by bin search now. Thank you